# Microsoft Entra ID multi-tenant client credentials flow

Tags: azure-active-directory

We have developed a multi-tenant HTTP API hosted in Azure, utilized by various daemon clients both on-premise and in the Azure Cloud.
These daemon clients are our creations so the API is the foundation upon which our other products depend. In terms of authentication, we implement the OAuth2 client credentials flow.
Currently, the API serves as a host for authorization (IdentityServer4). Consequently, the resource server and authorization server are co-deployed. This setup enables the creation of multiple OAuth2 clients per tenant. The acr_values play a crucial role on the token endpoint, facilitating the transmission of tenant information.

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://localhost:44317/connect/token' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'client_id=1337c7c2-3f42-41bb-9ba9-2c85cacfaa4b&client_secret=test&grant_type=client_credentials&acr_values=tenant%3Atenant-a'
```

Currently, we are exploring the use of Microsoft Entra ID as our authorization server. Protecting the API itself appears straightforward through a multi-tenant app registration. As for client app registrations, we are considering a few options:

#### 1. Multi-Tenant App Registration in Home Tenant per Daemon Client

Using a multi-tenant app registration in our home tenant for each daemon client poses challenges. It would entail using the same secret among all customers, which is not ideal, especially for on-premise daemons where secure secret storage is hard. Additionally, we aim to maintain authentication isolation between our tenants.

#### 2. Single-Tenant App Registration in Customer's Entra ID per Daemon Client

Using a single-tenant app registration in the customer's Entra ID for each daemon client offers the advantage of providing each customer with its own secret. However, a notable drawback is that the responsibility of configuring and rotating the secret falls on the customer. This arrangement feels awkward, particularly as we are both the developers of the client and API. Having authentication mediated through our customer, especially in machine-to-machine flows, adds an additional layer that seems weird.

#### 3. Single-Tenant App Registration in Home Tenant per Daemon Client, per Tenant

Creating a single-tenant app registration in our home tenant for each daemon client, per tenant, could address the issue of shared secrets. However, identifying the tenant becomes challenging, as all clients would originate from the same issuer.

#### 4. Internal Setup of Entra ID Tenant per Customer

Establishing an Entra ID tenant internally for each customer and configuring the clients within offers the advantage of each customer having its own secret. Tenants can be distinguished since tokens will be issued by different Entra ID instances. However, this option raises concerns about maintenance, given the substantial number of customers (100) and client apps (5+) resulting in the management of 500 app registrations, including secret rotations, presenting a potential maintenance nightmare.

In our current solution with IdentityServer4, we've developed a user interface for configuring clients per tenant. The solutions involving Microsoft Entra ID appear considerably more complex than what we currently have, unless there's something we might be overlooking?